# Turning an Object into a string in PHP

Tags: php

I'm creating a filter tab in a WordPress site.

The problem is simple: it's a Real Estate Themed website. There's a list of properties(some are for sale and the others are for rent).

The Price is displayed using an Object:

```
$my_property->price()
```

I want to be able to check if there's the word 'Monthly' in the price to be able to know which is on sale and which is for rent.

I can do that using the `strstr` function in PHP but I cant use it on an object.

How can i turn the output of `$my_property->price()` into a string to able to manipulate it and use it in my `if` statement?

Note: gettype($my_property) is Object and gettype($my_property->price()) is returning the price with NULL attached to it.

**Example:**

// Normal Outcome 
$my_property->price() will return example: $850,000,00

// Gettype Outcome 
gettype($my_property->price()) will return $850,000,00NULL

The Output of `$my_property->price()` is the price of the property.

```
<header class="entry-header">
   <h3 class="entry-title">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
     <span class="price"><?php $my_property->price() ?></span>
   </h3>
</header>
```

If the Property is for Rent, The Word *Monthly* will display next to the price, So using this word i will be able to differentiate between what property is on sale and which one is for rent. So i need to make some **condition statements** centered around the presence of *Monthly* in the Price.
I Cant do the price is under the *Object* type. Is there anyway i can assign the content of this object to a new variable so that i can that instead? or If anyone have another idea to work this out it would be great too.

Comment: What does `$my_property->price()` actually return?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($my_property->price());` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the output of `'<pre>', var_dump($my_property->price()), '</pre>';`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5A6D.png

Code Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyOcA.png

Comment: That really doesn't look like `var_dump()` output to me. It should show the _type_ and the _value_.  What's in the class itself? Can you show that - or at least the `price()` method?

Comment: Yes give me a second to find where they placed the method

Comment: @DarenChandisingh Im waiting for the staff to point me to the location even tho i made a project search for the method but didnt get anything. As soon as i have a screenshot or a code snippet i will let you know

Answer (score 0):

If the response is a string then you can do something like:

```
<?php
$extraClass = '';
$price = $my_property->price();
if (false !== strpos($price, 'Monthly)) {
    $extraClass = 'rental';
}
?>
<span class="price <?php $extraClass><"><?php $price ?></span>
```

Or something like that, depending on why you actually want to test for rental.

Comment: the problem is, i cant assign $my_property->price() to a variable, i tried the same thing above but didn't workout

Comment: @robingeagea do a `var_dump($my_property->price())` and show us the result.

Comment: $price = var_dump($my_property->price()) ?

Comment: I tried that now, Lets say the $my_property->price() returns  $825,000.00, Now that returns $825,000.00NULL and the $price didnt get the value of $my_property->price() :/

Comment: @robingeagea no, do something like `echo '<pre>', var_dump($my_property->price()), '</pre>';` and just show us what it's returning. What's the full output? (Or view source to see it)

Comment: Alright, it returns: $825,000.00NULL both in source and on the page

Comment: Is that really all? If it's a `var_dump()` I'd expect it to look more like `string(11) "£825,000.00"` or something @robingeagea

Comment: What does the method `price()` look like? Can you paste the class into your question?

Comment: @robingeagea Please do the `var_dump()` thing and not `gettype()`.

Comment: yes i pasted what you sent me `echo '<pre>', var_dump($my_property->price()), '</pre>';`

Answer (score 0):

Thats the Code in the Backend related to showing the price:

```
  /**
     * Display property price
     */
    public function price() {
        if ( ! $this->property_id ) {
            return false;
        }
        echo $this->get_price();
    }

    /**
     * Returns property price
     * @return string price
     */
    public function get_price() {
        if ( ! $this->property_id ) {
            return null;
        }
        $price_amount = doubleval( $this->get_property_meta( $this->meta_keys[ 'price' ] ) );
        $price_postfix = $this->get_property_meta( $this->meta_keys[ 'price_postfix' ] );
        return $this->format_price( $price_amount, $price_postfix );
    }

    /**
     * Provide formatted price
     *
     * @param int|double|float $price_amount    price amount
     * @param string $price_postfix    price post fix
     * @return null|string  formatted price
     */
    public static function format_price ( $price_amount, $price_postfix = '' ) {
```

Comment: @DarenChandisingh thats it!

Comment: Hey @DarenChandisingh, Thx a lot for the help, really! I fixed the issue, changed the code inside the class and it worked!